# Change dynamically facebook app id at runtime

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-facebook-login

I am trying to change the facebook app id from remote dynamically at runtime.
Currently I am using a library for Flutter Facebook login, but I can't change the value of the Facebook application id, like I saw in an Apple library.

I am trying right now to send the desired Facebook application id via a Flutter chanel, get it in the Android code and then set it via FacebookSDK.setApplicationId method.
This is a very complex way, which is very hard to maintain and get the Facebook values that I need.
I wonder if there is a better way to do that, or if do you think it will not works.

Comment: I needed the exact same solution. My app uses one Facebook App for authenticating users, one is for Facebook graph API.

Comment: Hey, were you able to get anywhere with it? Stuck in the same situation.